# Monitor loses signal when switching users

Tags: display, graphics, signal

Periodically when I log off from Windows my monitor will lose signal. The machine powers down normally when I press the power button on the case so I think it is running normally aside from that.

I've tried updating to the latest graphics drivers but the problem persists. I've ensured I'm running in the proper resolution. I've tried unplugging the monitor and plugging it back in and it still gets no signal. This leads me to believe it's the graphics card..

It is a GT 430 outputting over DVI to a 20 inch Acer monitor.

I've googled around but nobody else seems to have this issue.

*** edit: the power shuts down when i press the power button on the case, not the monitor ***

Comment: Turning your monitor off will never affect your computer's power... are you sure that's what you're pushing?  Are you selecting 'LOG OFF', or maybe 'SLEEP' or 'SHUTDOWN' instead?  You have to be exact in what you say, because what you're describing cannot happen.  What OS?  Probably Windows.  If you select SLEEP or SHUTDOWN, the computer turns off, the monitor signal goes away (of course, as expected) and the monitor will possibly display "no signal" and then turn itself off too if left alone for a moment.  Are you SURE you're just selecting LOG-OFF?  And WHAT device's power button?

Comment: Sorry! I meant to say the pwr button on the case of my computer. This is Windows, yes. Sleep works fine and wakes up fine. This happens when I press logoff or switch user, sometimes the screen will go black "no signal" and stay there. Most of the time it goes black and then displays the logon screen like normal.